# undefined is not a function in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, workflow

I am using backbone and a workflow.js extension with to set up flow of my application. I have following backbone model

```
var InvoiceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    workflow: {
        initial: 'draft',

        events: [
            { name: 'issue', from: 'draft', to: 'issued' },
            { name: 'payout', from: 'issued', to: 'paid' },
            { name: 'cancel', from: 'draft', to: 'canceled' },
            { name: 'cancel', from: 'issued', to: 'canceled' }
        ]
    },

    initialize: function () {
        _.extend(this, new Backbone.Workflow(this, { attrName: 'status' }));
    }

});
```

I am using above model like below

```
    var invoiceModel = new InvoiceModel();
    console.log(invoiceModel.get('status'));

    invoiceModel.triggerEvent('issue'); // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Somehow when I use `triggerEvent()` function is returns `undefined is not a function`. **Why and how I can fix this error?**

**UPDATE**

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zvvtpuse/)

Comment: Can you create an example of this code in jsfiddle/other application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `triggerEvent()` hides in the prototype of the `Workflow` object.

`_.extend()` only copies object's own properties without properties from the prototype.

Your example will work with:

```js
initialize: function () {
    _.extend(this, (new Backbone.Workflow(this, {
        attrName: 'status'
    })).__proto__, new Backbone.Workflow(this, {
        attrName: 'status'
    }));
}
```

As you can see, I explicitly added a prototype to the extend chain.

Know that it's a very inelegant solution. Though I didn't find a better one yet, I hope it will explain your problem.

---

This also works:

```js
var Workflow = new Backbone.Workflow(this, {
    attrName: 'status'
});
_.extend(this, Workflow);
$.extend(this, Workflow);
```

Here Underscore copies `Workflow`s own properties (`model`) and jQuery deep-copies the properties from the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

`triggerEvent` is not a Backbone.Model method. You use `trigger` to emit an event. If that `triggerEvent` is coming from your Workflow library (I couldn't find any link/info after a quick googling) then you're probably setting up your classes wrong.

I don't think your initialize method is quite right, but without seeing the Workflow docs I can't tell you more.

However, the general pattern to augment Backbone components is to extend the Model definition's prototype with another class methods, not extending the class *instance* (`this` in your `initialize` method) with a *new* instance.

I'm pretty sure that's where the bug lies. ;)

Comment: I'm sure it's not there, here you may find workflow.js documentation https://github.com/kendagriff/workflow.js

Comment: triggerEvent is in workflow.js(https://github.com/kendagriff/workflow.js/blob/master/workflow.js) please see line 40.